# Make ScrollPane fit to its parent in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I want to resize ScrollPane as it fits to its the parent container. I tested this code:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.setPrefSize(600, 600);
        vb.setMaxSize(600, 600);

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setFitToHeight(false);
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(false);

        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);

        VBox vb2 = new VBox();

        vb.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.getChildren().add(vb2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vb);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Now I want to make scrollPane width, height same as outer VBox(vb). But I was failed! Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't do that:

```
vb.getChildren().add(vb);
```

adding the VBox 'vb' to itself will cause an Exception and makes no sense :D

Secondly use an AnchorPane and set the constraints for the ScrollPane like this:

```
//Create a new AnchorPane
AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();

//Put the AnchorPane inside the VBox
vb.getChildren().add(anchorPane);

//Fill the AnchorPane with the ScrollPane and set the Anchors to 0.0
//That way the ScrollPane will take the full size of the Parent of
//the AnchorPane (here the VBox)
anchorPane.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
//Add content ScrollPane
scrollPane.getChildren().add(vb2);
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, your code won't even compile because `ScrollPane` can't invoke `getChildren()` method, it has protected access. Use `scrollPane.setContent(vb2);` instead.

Second - calling `vb.getChildren().add(vb);` does not make any sense because you are trying to add `Node` to himself. It will throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: cycle detected:`

Next if you want `ScrollPane` to fit `VBox` size use following code:

```
vb.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
VBox.setVgrow(scrollPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

scrollPane.setContent(vb2);
```